# R: Merge 2 Data Frame by Multiple Condition Using Dates & ID

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, lookup

I am trying to merge 2 data frame using multiple conditions and have used merge command but unable to get a successful output.

```
#Data Frame df1#
ID<- c("A1", "A2","A3", "A4")
Location <- c("012A","234B","012A","238C" )
startdate <- as.Date(c("2014-11-01","2014-01-01","2015-10-01", "2015-01-01"))
enddate <- as.Date(c("2014-12-31","2014-08-31","2015-12-31","2015-12-31"))
df1<- data.frame(ID,Location, startdate, enddate)

#Data Frame df2#
ID<-c("A1", "A1", "A4")
N<- c(2,1,2)
Loss_Date <- as.Date(c("2014-11-15", "2015-12-25", "2015-11-30"))
Amt<-c("2200","1000", "500")
df2<- data.frame(ID, N, Loss_Date,Amt)
```

**I want to merge these 2 dataframe by using Location as common column and  Loss_Date in df2 lies between (inclusive) Start_Date and End_Date in df2.** You can see that second entry in df2 doesnt get mapped as the date is not in range of df1

```
#Required Output
ID<- c("A1", "A2","A3", "A4")
Location <- c("012A","234B","012A","238C" )
startdate <- as.Date(c("2014-11-01","2014-01-01","2015-10-01", "2015-01-01"))
enddate <- as.Date(c("2014-12-31","2014-08-31","2015-12-31","2015-12-31"))
N<-c(2,0,0,2)
Loss_Date <- c("2014-11-15", "NA", "NA", "2015-11-30")
Amt<-c("2200","0","0", "500")
Output<- data.frame(ID,Location, startdate, enddate,N, Loss_Date,Amt)
```

I created a common ID using the Year and ID but get the wrong mapping. Tried various ways to use merge and match but the command doesn work. I need this to run on over 170K observations. Both data frame are of unequal length. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your first issue is that in `df1` the column `Location` matches with the column `ID` in `df2`. Is that a typing error, or this is how you have your data?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I have fixed this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just added a little bit of extra code in @VincentBoned 's answer.

```
# create 1st dataframe
ID<- c("A1", "A2","A3", "A4")
Location <- c("012A","234B","012A","238C" )
startdate <- as.Date(c("2014-11-01","2014-01-01","2015-10-01", "2015-01-01"))
enddate <- as.Date(c("2014-12-31","2014-08-31","2015-12-31","2015-12-31"))

df1<- data.frame(ID,Location, startdate, enddate, stringsAsFactors = F)


# create 2nd dataframe
ID<-c("A1", "A1", "A4")
N<- c(2,1,2)
Loss_Date <- as.Date(c("2014-11-15", "2015-12-25", "2015-11-30"))
Amt<-c("2200","1000", "500")

df2<- data.frame(ID, N, Loss_Date,Amt, stringsAsFactors = F)


library(dplyr)

full_join(df1, df2, by="ID") %>% 
  mutate(condition = (Loss_Date >= startdate & Loss_Date <= enddate)) %>%
  mutate(N = ifelse(condition & !is.na(condition), N, 0)) %>%
  mutate(Loss_Date = as.Date(ifelse(condition, Loss_Date, NA),origin="1970-01-01")) %>%
  mutate(Amt = ifelse(condition & !is.na(condition), Amt, 0)) %>%
  select(-condition) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%                              # for each ID
  mutate(Nrows = n()) %>%                       # count how many rows they have in the final table
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(!(Nrows > 1 & is.na(Loss_Date))) %>%   # filter out rows with IDs that have more than 1 rows and those rows are not matched
  select(-Nrows)

#   ID Location  startdate    enddate N  Loss_Date  Amt 
# 1 A1     012A 2014-11-01 2014-12-31 2 2014-11-15 2200 
# 2 A2     234B 2014-01-01 2014-08-31 0       <NA>    0 
# 3 A3     012A 2015-10-01 2015-12-31 0       <NA>    0 
# 4 A4     238C 2015-01-01 2015-12-31 2 2015-11-30  500
```

If you understood how the above code works (step by step) you can use a more compact version that returns the same result:

```
full_join(df1, df2, by="ID") %>% 
  mutate(condition = (Loss_Date >= startdate & Loss_Date <= enddate),
         N = ifelse(condition & !is.na(condition), N, 0),
         Loss_Date = as.Date(ifelse(condition, Loss_Date, NA),origin="1970-01-01"),
         Amt = ifelse(condition & !is.na(condition), Amt, 0)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%                             
  mutate(Nrows = n()) %>%                      
  filter(!(Nrows > 1 & is.na(Loss_Date))) %>%
  select(-c(condition, Nrows))
```

Comment: I simply used the following command before select (-condition) which seem to worked. Thanks for your responses and helps really appreciate it. filter(condition == TRUE | is.na(condition)== TRUE) %>%

Comment: Though these solutions works but one problem I still have with my original data set and unfortunately can't share that. BUt if I can explain : I want these 2 conditions applied at the same time because if I don't do that one of my row in df2 can be matched multiple times if I just do by ID in df1 and when I subsequently remove these rows with False indicator I remove the original row in df1 as well.

Comment: I just want to map the rows in df2 to df1 which meets both conditions that is ID and date and res could be either NA or 0

Comment: Can you create an example where I'll apply this process and will create that problem? Can't see how the process will affect your original data frame.

Comment: So just to be complete duplicate records in df1 should not get created if there is no match

Comment: `df1` doesn't change at any point. Multiple rows for a specific `ID` might be created at some point during the process but not in your original `df1`. Then, if there's no match they will be excluded. The result is a new data frame and not an updated `df1`.

Comment: Thanks I understand. What I meant is when you create a new data frame, specific ID gets created and when the process it removes it removes several rows which it should not. I will try to post this with a new question and bigger data set which is more representative with a specific challenge in this code.

Comment: Yes, try to use a dataset that will have this problem so I can fix my code. Maybe it's better to update this question as the new one might be considered as duplicate.

Comment: However the last filter in my code removes rows that have NA Loss_Date only from IDs with multiple rows. But maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4):

In the current development version of *data.table* (v1.9.7), non-equi joins are implemented. With that we can do:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.7+
setDT(df2)[df1, .(ID, Location, startdate, enddate, N, x.Loss_Date, Amt), 
                      on=.(ID, Loss_Date>=startdate, Loss_Date<=enddate)]
#    ID Location  startdate    enddate  N x.Loss_Date  Amt
# 1: A1     012A 2014-11-01 2014-12-31  2  2014-11-15 2200
# 2: A2     234B 2014-01-01 2014-08-31 NA        <NA>   NA
# 3: A3     012A 2015-10-01 2015-12-31 NA        <NA>   NA
# 4: A4     238C 2015-01-01 2015-12-31  2  2015-11-30  500
```

Answer (score 3):

I've done the merge using package `dplyr` which is really fast and easy to use.

You should add to your data frame definition this `stringsAsFactors=F`

```
 df1<- data.frame(ID,Location, startdate, enddate, stringsAsFactors = F)
 df2<- data.frame(ID, N, Loss_Date,Amt, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

So your character inputs don't get changed to factors and they don't give you undesired results

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

output <- full_join(df1, df2, by="ID") %>% 
filter(Loss_Date >= startdate & Loss_Date <= enddate)
```

Output:

```
  ID Location  startdate    enddate N  Loss_Date  Amt
1 A1     012A 2014-11-01 2014-12-31 2 2014-11-15 2200
2 A4     238C 2015-01-01 2015-12-31 2 2015-11-30  500
```

Again, as appointed by the comments, if you want to preserve the rows that doesn't match the condition, you should use another function:

```
output2 <- left_join(df1, df2, by="ID") %>% 
 mutate(condition = (Loss_Date >= startdate & Loss_Date <= enddate)) %>%
 mutate(N = ifelse(condition & !is.na(condition), N, 0)) %>%
 mutate(Loss_Date = as.Date(ifelse(condition, Loss_Date, NA),origin="1970-01-01")) %>%
 mutate(Amt = ifelse(condition & !is.na(condition), Amt, 0)) %>%
 mutate(condition = ifelse(is.na(condition),T,condition)) %>%
 filter(condition) %>%
 select(-condition)
```

First create a new column that matches the condition, and then change the other columns to `0`or `NA` according to that condition. Lastly, unselect the new generated column. (Notice that `ifelse` changes the class of `Date` to `numeric`so an `as.Date` is needed)

```
  ID Location  startdate    enddate N  Loss_Date  Amt
1 A1     012A 2014-11-01 2014-12-31 2 2014-11-15 2200
2 A2     234B 2014-01-01 2014-08-31 0       <NA>    0
3 A3     012A 2015-10-01 2015-12-31 0       <NA>    0
4 A4     238C 2015-01-01 2015-12-31 2 2015-11-30  50
```

Comment: Maybe instead of a `filter` use a `mutate` to return `NA`, `0`, or the actual value based on your condition, in order to match @Adi 's desired output?

Comment: Sure, if that's his desired output, you're right, and `mutate` should be used instead of  `filter`...  I've edited it, but I don't know a more efficient (and short and clean) way to do it

Comment: I think you returned the values the other way around.

Comment: Was there any point where you transformed `Amt` to numeric? Because the initial code given by @Adi has the `Amt` values as character. Maybe that's also an initial typing mistake.

Comment: @AntoniosK no, I haven't transformed `Amt` to numeric, I used the input definition of @Adi.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with updating the question. Now `Amt` is a factor if you run the process from the beginning (`Amt<-c("2200","1000", "500")`) and that creates a problem.

Comment: Thanks all but one point that has been missed in solution (i think) is that there 2 conditions to be met for every entry in df2 to be mapped to df1. For example row 2 have the same ID but cant be matched to df1 as loss date outside the start and end date

Comment: What I included was a `stringsAsFactors = F` at the definition... but well, when @Adi appears he can explain a bit more about the input / output

Comment: Also, I can't find full_join function as my R is throwing error and cant see any documentation on that

Comment: @Adi, install package `dplyr` and `tidyr`

Comment: @vicent - It seems tidyr is not available for R Studio version 3.0.3

Comment: Do you really need `tidyr`? I think @Adi updated his question and your initial merging now has to be by `ID` and not `Location`.

Comment: No he doesnt really need it. And yes, he has changed the column to ID. I'm making an edition now.

Comment: Guys, apologies for changes but I am still learning to use this platform. Never used the blogs before.

Comment: @Adi, after my changes and yours I think that my proposed `output` is what you're looking for. Now only rows 1 and 3 from df2 are matched to df1

Comment: I would propose a small change like : `mutate(N = ifelse(condition==FALSE | is.na(condition), 0, N))` so you can get a more "symmetric" output (don't have 0s and NAs in same column).

Comment: You can see that the 2nd row returns values for `N` and `Amt`. If you want to use the opposite of my suggestion above you have to do : `mutate(N = ifelse(condition & !is.na(condition), N, 0))`.

Comment: full_join function doesn't work and I already have dplyr as installed package?

Comment: @AntoniosK, thanks for your suggestions. I prefer, in general, using `!`

Comment: @Adi that sounds not possible. `dplyr` is installed but you have to call it as well. Try to run `library(dplyr)` first and then run the code.

Comment: @Antonios : What version of dplyr you are using? I have 0.2 which i guess is published on cran

Comment: Also, I dont see anything in the documentation of dplyr. I am only aware of inner_join , left-join etc.

Comment: @Adi , i'm using `dplyr` version 0.4.2. But anyway, in this particular case, i think you could use `left_join`

Comment: Thanks. I had to update the R version. Should have checked for updates along with R Studio. Function works but the length of the data.frame should be same as df1 and the extar row number 2 is not required. We want to match df 2 to df 1 and and addition rows are removed from df2

Comment: Guys, any way to remove the row 2 as this is not part of my original dataset df1. I only want to keep size of the data frame equal to df1. I have tried using subset or other join functions but it seem to treat NA in row 3 and 4 as FALSE. If you see my output I don't want row 2.

Comment: @Adi @AntoniosK I've added a change. If condition takes the value of NA, it means that `Loss_Date` doesn't exist, so it's a row that doesn't exist in `df2`. So, changing the NA for TRUE  and filtering preserves all the rows from `df1`

Answer (score 1):

sqldf is very robust and easy to read. Check this code out:

```
library(sqldf)
Output<-sqldf("
           SELECT L.*, r.N, r.Loss_Date, r.Amt
           FROM df1 as L
           LEFT JOIN df2 as r
           ON 
           L.ID=r.ID AND
              r.Loss_Date BETWEEN L.startdate AND L.enddate
           ORDER BY L.ID")
```

where "L" represents df1 (that's the df1 as l), and "r" represents df2 (df2 as r).